# Cron Job with timeout

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to provide timeout to kubernetes CronJob?

I need to schedule a task that runs according to Cron schedule but I need to limit execution of this task to only 20 seconds. If the task runs longer than 20 seconds than it should be terminated. 
I tried using `.spec.startingDeadlineSeconds` but this didn't help.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Use `cronjob.spec.jobTemplate.spec.activeDeadlineSeconds`:

> FIELDS:
>
> activeDeadlineSeconds   
>        Specifies the duration in seconds relative to the startTime that the job
>        may be active before the system tries to terminate it; value must be
>        positive integer

[From documentation:](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#job-termination-and-cleanup)

> Another way to terminate a Job is by setting an active deadline. Do
>   this by setting the .spec.activeDeadlineSeconds field of the Job to a
>   number of seconds.
>
> The activeDeadlineSeconds applies to the duration of the job, no
>   matter how many Pods are created. Once a Job reaches
>   activeDeadlineSeconds, all of its Pods are terminated and the Job
>   status will become type: Failed with reason: DeadlineExceeded.

Comment: I am putting a +1 on this, as this is actually a question in the Kubernetes certification exam.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: is it possible that WITHOUT this directive, kubernetes may start more than one copy of the same job that's already running just because it may take an hour to complete?

Comment: @JasonGenX, in my recent personal experience, yes, it is very possible for Kubernetes Cron Job to have more than one instance of a job running if an old one hasn't exited by the time the next one is scheduled to start.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a simple example taken from https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/ and modified with an hour timeout added:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      activeDeadlineSeconds: 3600
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```